Group of assassins that is trying to kill each other until one is left
I don't remember very much of the movie, but here is some:

There is a group of assassins that is trying to kill each other till one is left.
I think there is a "event" like this every year.
Film is from 2006-2015
The main character has a normal person with him everywhere.
The movie is in English.


Possibly The Tournament (2009)

Every seven years in an unsuspecting town, The Tournament takes place.
  A battle royale between 30 of the world's deadliest assassins. The
  last man standing receiving the $10,000,000 cash.





Yes it was! Thank you very much.
